# How to enable Firebase after setting "firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled" to "false" and retrieve a token/push messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem receiving any tokens or push notifications with my custom FirebaseMessagingService, after i disabled the auto initialisation of firebase messaging by setting the key `firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled` to `false` in my AndroidManifest.xml.

When not setting the key to `false` my Service does receive a token.
I mean it is obvious, that i do need to initialise firebase messaging in order to retrieve a token, but all methods i tried did not seems to work.

In order to prevent legal problems i only want to enable firebase/server communication after the user of my Android app did accept the terms of use.
That is why i want to prevent the auto initialisation. After the user did accept the terms of use i want initialise the app and send my retrieved token to my backend.

Methods i already tried:

`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(<Context>)`
`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(true)`

I can actually get a token by using the method `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstance()` but i would really prefer to use my FirebaseMessagingService which seems to be the much cleaner way.

Here is some of the code in my AndroidManifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
    <service
        android:name="de.itkl.smartmobile.module.push.implementation.SMPushMessageService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Share your Activity when you are calling FirebaseApp.initializeApp(<Context>) FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(true)

Comment: I call these methods in a class which is not extending Activity but in a method of a class which is doing nothing else. If you think, that the context being null could be the problem, i can tell you, that this is not the case for sure.

Comment: Did you try this  from Google? Could you try it from a Activity for testing purpose?

https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/28489e59e4a4f46a4af7d2e007bda53020b15bc2/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/messaging/MainActivity.java#L39-L39

Comment: I did already try this method and waited around half a minute for `onNewToken(String token)` to be called, but that sadly did not happen